# Ionic 2 ion-slides image auto landscape size

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want the images in ion-slide automatically into landscape.
Its look good on landscape view, but not good on potrait view.

Here the screen shoot.

[image]
[image]

and here my source code of the ionic 2 "ion-slides".

```
<ion-slides pager">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of banner">
                <img src="https://bawanatravel.com/uploads/images/blocks/{{slide.gambar}}">
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Hope some one can help me, thanks.

Comment: I looked at the source of properties but could not find anything relevant to sizing, keep us posted if you have arrived at a solution.  Thank you. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/slides/slides.ts